# Why can't I access any of my Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, react-native, javascript-objects

First, here is my object list as it looks console.logged. Note that these values change each time a new article is selected since the words are picked at random, along with their positions. The following objects are stored in a dropAreaValues state:

```
{}
2
:
{y: 363, width: 50, x: 288, height: 1}
17
:
{y: 129.5, width: 50, x: 0, height: 1}
26
:
{y: 380, width: 50, x: 195.5, height: 1}
64
:
{y: 45.5, width: 50, x: 247, height: 1}
67
:
{y: 12.5, width: 50, x: 65.5, height: 1}
194
:
{y: 129.5, width: 50, x: 161, height: 1}
203
:
{y: 396.5, width: 50, x: 249.5, height: 1}
209
:
{y: 29, width: 50, x: 197.5, height: 1}
219
:
{y: 413.5, width: 50, x: 101, height: 1}
223
:
{y: 346.5, width: 50, x: 251.5, height: 1}
```

What I'm attempting to do is map or reduce an array of all the article keys and return each key paired with the above object so that it returns the values of each object.

```
articleKeys array: ["2", "17", "26", "64", "67", "194", "203", "209", "219", "223"]
```

Some more code. wordAreas is the dropAreaValues object as shown above.

```
getNestedObjects(wordAreas, articleKeys){
      articleKeys.map((key, index) => {
        //this part is to simply check the values in the console
        console.log(wordAreas[key], key, wordAreas, articleKeys);
      }, {});
    }
```

getNestedObjects is called in componentWillMount() call, using `this.getNestedObjects(this.state.dropZoneValues, this.state.articleKeys)`

Now, when I console.log this out, I would expect the values in wordAreas[key] to be returned for each key that is passed. However, this example is what I get in the whole console.log :

```
undefined "194" {} [Array(10)]
```

Explanation of above: [Array(10)] are the 10 keys from articleKeys. "194" is the value of the key returned during the reduce loop. {} is the object that, when expanded, shows all the objects with keys in said object.

"undefined" is where the values should be returned. wordAreas[key] for 194 should show {y: 129.5, width: 50, x: 161, height: 1} but instead it returns as undefined.

I've been working on this off and on for the past couple of weeks (this is a personal project of mine) but I can't figure out why it's not returning the object's key's values.I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what it is exactly.

What I want to do is to take the values of each of these objects and put them into a separate component that will be rendered onto the screen using the x/y values. I'm console.logging to simply check the results, but trying to return the object's value using wordAreas[key] is continuing to return undefined.

Thank you for any assistance you may give me.

Comment: `.map` creates a new array based on a transformation applied to each element of the first array. If you're not using a new array, use `forEach` instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. I should mention that I am using React Native, and I'm not sure how this changes things.

While forEach does work, I still receive undefined for `wordAreas[key]`

`articleKeys.forEach(function(key){
        console.log(key, wordAreas[key])
      })`

Comment: first thought: .map function should have a return statement. please post the complete code or codepen/fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve been burned by something similar before. I would try `wordAreas[parseInt(key)]`.

Comment: I'Ve also tried this. Doesn't work, it still gives me undefined.

Comment: Hmm.. In your code example, why are you calling map() on the first element of articleKeys?

Comment: That was a typo on my part when I was typing this in. Fixed.